# Unable to use heroku gem cli after password changes

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

I changed my password via the web interface. And now I can't run any command that requires authentication. Password is using plain ASCII, nothing fancy, no Unicode, weird non-printable characters, etc.

Anyone had similar experience and how you manage to resolve.

How do I even begin to go about debug this? Any verbose cli option, log I can review?

```
% sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X 
ProductVersion: 10.6.8 
BuildVersion:   10K549
% rvm --version
rvm 1.10.3 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/
% ruby --version 
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0] 
% gem --version 
1.8.17 
% heroku version 
2.25.0 
% cat ~/.netrc # is empty 
% heroku auth:login

Enter your Heroku credentials. 
Email: me@example.com
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Authentication failed.
```

Comment: did you find solution? I'm stuck with same issue

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had this same problem after changing the password, and I found it was because I was managing multiple accounts with the [heroku-accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) gem.

I removed the account setup in heroku-accounts and then re-added it, using the new credentials to authenticate. Things then started working as before.

It seems that the authentication details stored in the heroku-accounts gem somehow override those you apply via the command line. Anyway, this worked for me.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. Remove accounts plugin, reinstall and boom, I'm back in business.

Comment: You might want to update your answer for a shorter and more stable solution in https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts/issues/56

Comment: A web search brought me here via https://github.com/scala-vienna/scala-vienna-web/issues/35 because logs on Heroku showed `Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)` and `body: "{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"Invalid credentials provided.\"}"` when trying to upload to Amazon's AWS. The API key on Heroku got re-generated for some reason, and after updating it using the CLI everything returned to normal. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this:

```
$ heroku accounts:remove your_app
```

followed immediately by

```
$ heroku accounts:add your_app
```

Enter your email and your new password, and you should be good to go.

Comment: You don't remove the app from accounts, you remove accounts from accounts.  Also, if you do this when you're currently using the account it will freeze and not let you re-add because it will keep saying the account doesn't exist.

Comment: @jake It does work, but you have to remove the account from somewhere that does not specify the given account as the current account.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to `heroku accounts` as detailed by @vaughanos in his answer. A quick way to fix this is.

Check the accounts you have

`heroku accounts`

> account1
>
> *account2

The `*` indicates the heroku account being used for the current project. This is the account you have done the password change for using the web interface.

Change the default account you have setup for this project

Either change it in `.git/config` or do a `heroku accounts:set account1`

Now do `heroku accounts:remove account2`

Now add it back with `heroku accounts:add account2`. Enter your email and new password. Everything will be setup up for you.

If it prompts you to update your `~/.ssh/config`, do it, but most likely that wouldn't require a change.

Answer (score 4):

For all the future error-Googlers out there:

The issue from 2013 has been fixed, however, after you change your password on the website, use the command:

`heroku login`

You will be prompted for your Heroku login and your new password. Goodbye weird "Authentication success. Authentication failure." errors.

via the Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication, about half-way down the page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows Vista.

I got authorization failed messages on every heroku command and wasn’t able to login.

```
c:\Sites\jut>heroku login
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Permission denied - C:/Users/myusername/_netrc (Errno::EACCES)
    Backtrace:   C:/Program Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/netrc-0.7.7/lib/netrc.rb:179:in `initialize'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/netrc-0.7.7/lib/netrc.rb:179:in `open'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/netrc-0.7.7/lib/netrc.rb:179:in `save'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:94:in `delete_credentials'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:40:in `login'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:31:in `login'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku login
    Version:     heroku/toolbelt/2.33.2 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.2
```

**I deleted
`C:/Users/myusername/_netrc`
where the passwords are stored.**

After that I was able to `heroku login` again and all went fine!

Comment: OMG, that works on Windows 7 also. I wanted to run Heroku from VM and synch repo through dropbox to make it work. Many thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

For me, following all the instructions on this page and uninstalling/reinstalling heroku toolbelt from their website did the trick.