# Brand new Heroku CLI installation authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

This question might be considered duplicate of this: [Unable to use heroku gem cli after password changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628149/unable-to-use-heroku-gem-cli-after-password-changes), but it is not.

In my case I have the latest Mac OS X 10.8.3 and I've installed brand new Heroku tool belt. First thing I've tried is to authenticate by issuing this:

```
heroku login
```

I was asked for my Heroku credentials, which I've entered (many-many times), but I got "Authentication Failed" message.

I've tried signing in with my credentials to Heroku website multiple times from different browsers - it all works, but I can't authenticate with Heroku CLI.

[image]

I don't have ~/.netrc file, I don't have any fancy firewall software on my Mac. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alex.

**Update 03/18/2013 9 PM Mountain:**

This is the Heroku issue and they are looking into it:
[image: Heroku login via CLI is broken]

Comment: It looks like this is a heroku issue, we're investigating.

Comment: Having the same issue here, and I am going crazy.  I've tried everything.  Please fix this!

Comment: That was quick - thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku engineers have fixed it and I was able to authenticate. Thank you, Heroku!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be an SSH key issue.

Here is a good guide to resolving it.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: Thank you, but probably not, because SSH keys are only used to push changes to the apps via Git. I'm just trying to authenticate to heroku via CLI, using my Heroku credentials - email and password. I might be wrong, but adding keys to Heroku is also possible via CLI... after I'm authenticated.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart - this is the very first steps to setup Heroku, SSH keys go after initial authentication via "heroku login".

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if there is a Heroku system problem?  I just tried to do Heroku login from my system and I'm getting the same message as you.  this hasn't been a problem before.

Comment: Possibly - did I crash Heroku? :)

Comment: just my two cents: I had the same issue for the past hour and this did work for me. you should give it a shot, although it's also totally possible that it crashed for a spell and now it's back up...

Comment: I think it was a Heroku authentication issue as it's working again now.